# Blackberry BrowserField2 extreemly slow loading times

Tags: blackberry, browserfield, load-time

I am currently trying to load some pages with a BrowserField2 but the loading time takes way to long. Loading the same page in the OS Browser works fine (<5 sec) but loading it within my app takes >30 seconds. What could be the reason? Here is my code:

```
            BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
                config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
                config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
                browserField = new BrowserField(config);

BrowserFieldListener listener = new BrowserFieldListener() {

                    public void documentCreated(BrowserField browserField, ScriptEngine scriptEngine, Document document) throws Exception{
                        // Show a loadinganimation
                    }           

                    public void documentLoaded(BrowserField browserField, Document document) throws Exception{
                        try{
                            // Hide a loadingAnimation
                        }catch(IllegalStateException es){
                            es.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

    browserField.addListener( listener );
```

I had the same problem before I implemented the BrowserFieldListener (and loading animation) so it has nothing to do with that. Have I missed something?

Comment: Have you solved this problem. Please let me know if you have solved and suggest how you did its so

Comment: Sorry m8, we even outsourced this to a BlackBerry expert and he failed to speed it up. Maybe there is a sollution now but I would suggest that you join some BlackBerry chat here and ask the gurus :)

Comment: Has anybody got an answer to this !! Or anything we can do from the Blackberry side to speed up the process ?